# Want to GROUP BY a combined set of all values contained in two similar columns (not by two separate columns)

Tags: mysql

I have a table ("Scores") with game scores. The table has a column for Team1 and a column for Team2 (the opponent of Team1) along with their scores in a game. Here's an example:

```
------------------------------------------
| id | Team1  | Score1 | Team2  | Score2 |
------------------------------------------
|  1 | Reds   |   1    | Blues  |   6    |
|  2 | Blues  |   5    | Greens |   2    |
|  3 | Greens |   3    | Whites |   4    |
|  4 | Whites |   0    | Greens |   7    |
------------------------------------------
```

What I want is a table ("GameCounts") with a count of how many games each team has played in, regardless of whether the team was Team1 or Team2. Here's the example I want:

```
-----------------------
|  Team  |  GameCount |
-----------------------
|  Reds  |      1     |
|  Blues |      2     |
| Greens |      3     |
| Whites |      2     |
-----------------------
```

After solving that, I'd like to formulate another table ("ScoreSum"), a list of each team with the sum of its scores:

```
-----------------------
|  Team  |  ScoreSum  |
-----------------------
|  Reds  |      1     |
-----------------------
|  Blues |     11     |
-----------------------
| Greens |     12     |
-----------------------
| Whites |      4     |
-----------------------
```

Every MySQL query I've tried has not come close at all. Thanks!

Comment: Well, let's see your best attempt so far. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Yep. Give a man a fish, and all that.

Comment: Well, yes, and though among many tries I did try a union of two matches of the same table, and had also recently encountered the need to do an "as" of derived tables, but none of my attempts parsed properly. I would rank my SQL experience to be informed but still nascent. I am still learning. Thanks for your comment, though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this all in one query by making a derived table of teams and scores, and then summing occurrences of each team name and their scores:

```
SELECT Team, COUNT(*) AS GameCount, SUM(Score) AS ScoreSum
FROM (SELECT Team1 AS Team,
             Score1 AS Score
      FROM Scores
      UNION ALL
      SELECT Team2 AS Team,
             Score2 AS Score
      FROM Scores) S
GROUP BY Team
```

Output:

```
Team    GameCount   ScoreSum
Blues   2           11
Greens  3           12
Reds    1           1
Whites  2           4
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4WoUhquRXLdmpg74as2vqw/0)

Comment: It works! Speedy response, much appreciated. I don't have sufficient reputation to vote up your response, but it was exactly what I needed.